# TLS certificate issue when KEDA trying to scale-up

Tags: rabbitmq, google-kubernetes-engine, azure-aks, keda

We are migrating from Azure to GCP. Our application is running in AKS. We use KEDA to scale up / create pods whenever there is a Message in Rabbit MQ.

We are using https protocol configured in KEDA for RabbitMQ. This works perfectly fine in AKS.

But when same app is migrated to GKE, with same setup, KEDA is failing to connect to RabbitMQ to get queue size. The error I am getting is as below.

`error inspecting rabbitMQ: Get "https://user:password@<Rabbit_MQ_Server>/api/queues/<vhost>/<queue_name>": x509: certificate signed by unknown authority`

The manifest files related to KEDA is like below. Which is same for both AKS & GKE. The Version of KEDA is also same. But the version of k8s is slightly different 1.23.12 for AKS & 1.24.10-gke.2300 for GKE.

```
apiVersion: keda.sh/v1alpha1
kind: TriggerAuthentication
metadata:
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
  name: keda-trigger-auth-rabbitmq
spec:
  secretTargetRef:
  - key: host
    name: keda-rabbitmq-secret
    parameter: host
---
apiVersion: v1
data:
  host: <base64 encoded rabbitMQ URL>
kind: Secret
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
  name: keda-rabbitmq-secret
type: Opaque
```

Any help on this is appreciated

Comment: Is RabbitMQ configured the same way on both GKE and AKS?  How are you creating the RabbitMQ cert on GKE versus AKS?

Comment: There was no certificate specified in AKS still it is working with AMQPS & HTTPS protocol. The same is not working in GKE.